# preg_match_all for magnet link

Tags: php

I want to use preg_match_all to get magnet links from threads then use the first magnet link.

I tried many patterns but nothing worked.

```
$uris = array();
preg_match_all('\'http://magnet:?\'', $post, $uris);
foreach ($uris[0] as $href) {
//////////////////////////////
$magnetUri = $href;
break;
}
```

Comment: Because magnet links MOST CERTAINLY do not have `http://` in them.

Comment: Read about what URI (and then URN and URL) means.

Comment: @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS even without `http://` it does not work.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan does this matter? i just need to get it out from the post with PHP function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to match `TTH` magnets using the `preg_match` call. Maybe, this will work for you:

```
preg_match( '/magnet:\?xt=urn:tree:tiger:(?P<tth>\w+)/', $rows['msg'], $matchTTH );
```

Ofcourse, I was storing the `TTH` of each magnet in this case, you can use any other of [these hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_uri#URN.2C_containing_hash_.28xt.29).

Comment: I have tried to edit it for BTIH but every time give me empty array. how to achieve that?

Comment: WORKED 100% . Thank you Doctor!